# Only displaying unique items in an array

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a geography quiz app on android studio. Part of this quiz app is using an ImageView to display different flags. I'm having trouble preventing the same flag from reappearing. I would like to randomly display flags but also prevent the same one reappearing. How can I do this?

This is my class containing the images:

```
package com.example.geonius;

public class containerfile {

public Integer [] Flags = {
        R.drawable.portugal,
        R.drawable.france,
        R.drawable.cuba,
        R.drawable.japan,
        R.drawable.southafrica,
        R.drawable.colombia,
        R.drawable.ethiopia,
        R.drawable.hungary,
        R.drawable.australia,
        R.drawable.cambodia,
        R.drawable.england,
        R.drawable.qatar,
        R.drawable.uae,
        R.drawable.kenya,
        R.drawable.india,
        R.drawable.china,
        R.drawable.nigeria,
        R.drawable.argentina,
        R.drawable.somalia,
        R.drawable.egypt,
        R.drawable.italy,
        R.drawable.usa
};

private String Choices [][] = {
        {"Portugal", "Spain", "Italy"},
        {"Netherlands", "France", "Germany"},
        {"Cuba", "Puerto Rico", "Panama"},
        {"Nepal", "Mongolia", "Japan"},
        {"Kenya", "Jamaica", "South Africa"},
        {"Venezuela", "Colombia", "Ecuador"},
        {"Ethiopia", "Eritrea", "Sudan"},
        {"Italy", "Hungary", "Lithuania"},
        {"New Zealand", "Fiji", "Australia"},
        {"Cambodia", "Vietnam", "Laos"},
        {"Iceland", "Finland", "England"},
        {"Qatar", "Argentina", "Bulgaria"},
        {"Bahrain", "Jordan", "UAE"},
        {"USA", "Kenya", "Sierra Leone"},
        {"Pakistan", "India", "Bangladesh"},
        {"China", "Russia", "Zimbabwe"},
        {"Nigeria", "Chile", "Czech Republic"},
        {"Bolivia", "Dominican Republic", "Argentina"},
        {"Somalia", "Djibouti", "Uganda"},
        {"Tunisia", "South Korea", "EGYPT"},
        {"Sweden", "Denmark", "Italy"},
        {"New zealand", "Slovakia", "United States of America"}

};

String CorrectChoice [] = {
  "Portugal",
  "France",
  "Cuba",
  "Japan",
  "South Africa",
  "Colombia",
  "Ethiopia",
  "Hungary",
  "Australia",
  "Cambodia",
  "England",
  "Qatar",
  "UAE",
  "Kenya",
  "India",
  "China",
  "Nigeria",
  "Argentina",
  "Somalia",
  "EGYPT",
  "Italy",
  "United States of America"

};

public Integer getFlags(int a) {
    Integer flags = Flags[a];
    return flags;
}

public String getOptions1(int a) {
    String options = Choices[a][0];
    return options;
}

public String getOptions2(int a) {
    String options = Choices[a][1];
    return options;
}

public String getOptions3(int a) {
    String options = Choices[a][2];
    return options;
}

public String getCorrectAnswers(int a) {
    String correctanswers = CorrectChoice[a];
    return correctanswers;
}

}
```

This is my java code underneath

```
 package com.example.geonius;

 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import java.util.Random;

public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button answer1, answer2, answer3;
TextView score, Lives;
ImageView flag;

private containerfile Flags = new containerfile();

private String Answer;
private Integer GameScore = 0;
private Integer Life = 3;
private int flagsLength = Flags.Flags.length;

Random key;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    key = new Random();

    answer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    answer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    answer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GameScore);
    Lives = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.life);
    flag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flags);

    score.setText("Score: " + GameScore);
    Lives.setText("Lives: " + Life);


    updateQuestion(key.nextInt(flagsLength));

    answer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (answer1.getText() == Answer) {
                GameScore++;
                score.setText("Score: " + GameScore);
                CorrectAnswer();
            }

            else if(Life == 0) {
                GameOver();
            }

            else if (answer1.getText() != Answer){
                Life--;
                Lives.setText("Lives: " + Life);
                NextQuestion();
            }
        }
    });

    answer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (answer2.getText() == Answer) {
                GameScore++;
                score.setText("Score: " + GameScore);
                CorrectAnswer();
            }

            else if(Life == 0) {
                GameOver();
            }

            else if (answer2.getText() != Answer){
                Life--;
                Lives.setText("Lives: " + Life);
                NextQuestion();
            }
        }
    });

    answer3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (answer3.getText() == Answer) {
                GameScore++;
                score.setText("Score: " + GameScore);
                CorrectAnswer();
            }

            if(Life == 0) {
                GameOver();
            }

            else if (answer3.getText() != Answer) {
                Life--;
                Lives.setText("Lives: " + Life);
                NextQuestion();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void updateQuestion(int num) {
    flag.setImageResource(Flags.getFlags(num));
    answer1.setText(Flags.getOptions1(num));
    answer2.setText(Flags.getOptions2(num));
    answer3.setText(Flags.getOptions3(num));

    Answer = Flags.getCorrectAnswers(num);

}

private void GameOver() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new           AlertDialog.Builder(Main3Activity.this);
    alert.setMessage("Game Over! You're score is " + GameScore).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("NEW GAME", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main3Activity.class));
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("EXIT GAME", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

private void CorrectAnswer() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main3Activity.this);
    alert.setMessage("Correct!").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Next Question", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            updateQuestion(key.nextInt(flagsLength));
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

private void NextQuestion() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main3Activity.this);
    alert.setMessage("Incorrect Answer. The correct answer was " + Answer).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Next Question", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            updateQuestion(key.nextInt(flagsLength));
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
 }
```

Comment: In regular ol' Java, the way to do this is to put the flags into a list, and then use `Collections.shuffle` to randomize them.  Then go through the list in order to display a random flag without repeating.

Answer (score 0):

**To prevent a flag to appear twice in a row** (if that is indeed what you are after):

Where you have

```
updateQuestion(key.nextInt(flagsLength));
```

you could do the following

1) first time you create a key, store it:

```
int currentKey = key.nextInt(flagsLength));
```

2) Then, when you generate a new key for the next question:

```
int nextKey;
do {
    nextKey = key.nextInt(flagsLength));
} while nextKey == currentKey;
currentKey = nextKey;
```

3) Finally, you can call `updateQuestion()`

```
updateQuestion(currentKey);
```

Comment: Your code just ensures two subsequent questions are not the same. But it is still possible to get 1st and 3rd questions to be the same. Better to generate collection of all question numbers `List<Integer> allQurstionNumbers =....;` and then shuffle it using `Collections.shuffle`